# How to merge list from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, join, stored-procedures, union

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetItemCategories]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --SELECT * FROM ItemCategories

    SELECT 
        IC.Id, IC.Name ,C.Id AS CompanyId, C.Name AS CompanName 
    FROM
        ItemCategories IC
    JOIN 
        CompanyItems CI ON IC.Id = CI.ItemCategoryId
    JOIN
        Companies C ON CI.CompanyId = C.Id
    --WHERE CI.CompanyId IN (SELECT TOP(100)* FROM Companies C)
END
```

This displays data like:

```
4   sdfs    14  Nestle
4   sdfs    15  Unilever
```

but I want to get like this:

```
4   sdfs    14  Nestle 
            15  Unilever
```

[image: check image for code]

Comment: or this equivalent in entityframework

Comment: You're confusing data with display rendering. The rendering you see in the  Results tab of SSMS isn't what the end user should see (unless you plan on modeling your application to look like SSMS)... Truing to force the database to do fhe job normally reserved for the application, will only cause grief once you get to the application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check this method but the same data.

```
declare @mytable table (compid int,compname varchar(20),itemid int, itemdesc varchar(20))

insert into @mytable
values 
(1,'Company A',100,'Nestle'),
(1,'Company A',200,'UniLever'),
(2,'Company B',300,'Citrix'),
(2,'Company B',400,'SQL'),
(2,'Company B',500,'Oracle'),
(1,'Company B',600,'Microsoft')


select 
 iif(left(m1.ord_id,1)>1,NULL,m.compid) [CompID],
 iif(left(m1.ord_id,1)>1,NULL,m.compname) [CompName],
 m.itemid,
 m.itemdesc
 from @mytable m
 inner join (
    select distinct compid,row_number() over (partition by compid order by itemid) [ord_id], itemid
    from @mytable) m1
    on m.compid = m1.compid and m.itemid = m1.itemid
```

or CTE

```
;with cte as
(
select distinct compid,row_number() over (partition by compid order by itemid) [ord_id], itemid 
from @mytable
) 
select 
 iif(left(m1.ord_id,1)>1,NULL,m.compid) [CompID],
 iif(left(m1.ord_id,1)>1,NULL,m.compname) [CompName],
 m.itemid,
 m.itemdesc
 from @mytable m
 inner join cte m1
 on m.compid = m1.compid and m.itemid = m1.itemid
```

if you are not happy with nulls replace the fields

```
iif(left(m1.ord_id,1)>1,'',cast(m.compid as varchar)) [CompID],
iif(left(m1.ord_id,1)>1,'',m.compname) [CompName],
```

Result

```
CompID  CompName    itemid  itemdesc
1       Company A   100     Nestle
                    200     UniLever
                    600     Microsoft
2       Company B   300     Citrix
                    400     SQL
                    500     Oracle
```

Comment: You are going through a lot of steps for mere presentation.  From a  database perspective, the OP's SQL is correct.  I would say they need to realize the difference between presentation and data.  NULL is not the solution IMO.  Don't you agree?

Comment: why don't you create your solution @smoore4 and let me be the judge. how's that?

Comment: NULL is just a result from SQL, you can always reformat it... it's a just a concept that there is a solution.

Comment: I know you want points.  We all do.  That doesn't mean that every question is justified and merits a response, even if it is possible.  The correct database approach is set-based.  Formatting data is the presentation layer.  I know you know that.  Have you ever written a query that requires the query output (not presentation) to look like this?  Not me.

Comment: i should say.. welcome to the world of SQL @smoore4 .. there is always a first for everything

Comment: var ss = (from ca in db.category
                          join j in db.itemCategories on ca.Id equals j.ItemCategoryId
                          join jC in db.company on j.CompanyId equals jC.Id
                          select new
                          {
                              ca,
                              jC
                          }).ToList();
this is with entity framework , how i get same result by using this